# Increase the size of new position form or allow expand it, just like in Gmail compose letter UI

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, user-experience

Every time I need to edit my developer story and type some info into job position form, I asking myself what was the reason to make this form so narrow:

[image]

It's so annoying to type a description of responsibilities in this tiny form. Please make just like in Gmail, where you can expand a compose text form and see the whole text you type without break lines after every three words!

Comment: Your browser appears to've already done that for you.  The diagonal lines in the lower right corner can be used to resize the textbox.

Comment: @DanNeely, yes, I'm aware about such feature, but IMHO it's a workaround, not a solution. The ideal way to solve it — to show a bigger form from the beginning or to allow to increase it like in Gmail.